# The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. Show ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: ssl, iis

We have SSL enabled site. Logged into System works fine. When we are trying to access approx 25 rows, System allows to display data. but we are trying to access a page with approx 1000 rows. We have used LinkButton to navigate through different number of rows.

I get this message from Firefox:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the
>   authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

Comment: Looks like the ssl protocol(SSL,TLS etc) or the ciphersuites used may be old ,please check your site with  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html .Also check with https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1058856

Comment: Thanks for feedback.

We have also tried with HTTP site, but the issue remains with HTTP. Today, we are trying with downloading file using HTTPs, but Browser status bar, we have observe "Performing TLS handshaking"..... which we didnot able to see in any Developer toolbar option, neither in  "Network" nor in "Console".

Comment: Can you give us little more information related to TLS.

We have checked our System settings, It shows that it uses SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0. Is this configuration causes any issue? If yes, then how to solve it?

Comment: thanks for all your reply